# Como representar este codigo html con helpers de razor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

tengo el siguiente código HTML:

```
 <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
       <label class="form-label">Tipo de dirección</label>
       <div class="form-inline">
          <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
             <input name="radio-direccion" value="local" type="radio" checked="checked" class="custom-control-input">
             <span class="custom-control-label">Local &nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
          </label>
          <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
             <input name="radio-direccion" value="foranea" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
             <span class="custom-control-label">Foránea</span>
          </label>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    window._getTipoDirUrl = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")';
 </script>
```

También una clase ViewModel que entre otras propiedades contiene esta:

```
public class DireccionViewModel
{
    ...
    [Display(Name = "Tipo dirección")]
    public string TipoDir {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Y un código javascript donde realizo una acción en función del radio button seleccionado:

```
 $("[name=radio-direccion]").on('change', function () {
    var $radio = $(this);
    $.ajax({
       url: window._getTipoDirUrl,
       data: { tipodir: $radio.val() },
       success: function (data) {
          $("#direccion").html(data);
       }
    });
 });
```

Necesito representar los inputs de radio con @Html.CheckBoxFor() de manera que cuando se haga el binding la propiedad TipoDir valga local o foranea (o alguna forma similar de manera que en el controlador yo sepa que opción se ha seleccionado) y que además el código javascript me funcione correctamente.

Comment: A que te refieres con "valga local o foránea"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a asumir que la clase `DireccionViewModel` es también el viewmodel de la vista razor, es decir que al principio de la vista hay una directiva `@model DireccionViewModel`. Así que modificaremos ese viewmodel para hacer lo que quieres.

### @Html.RadioButtonFor()

Imagino que quieres convertir ese código html y usar el razor helper Html.RadioButtonFor en vez de CheckBoxFor porque si usas check boxes estarías permitiendo multiples tipos de dirección y es contradictorio que sea local y también foránea.

Html.RadioButtonFor es el helper que renderiza un radio button con los parámetros que le pasamos. El tema con este helper es que solo renderiza un radio button - que no es de mucha ayuda si lo usas solo. Por eso lo que normalmente haces es renderizar dos o más.

### El ViewModel

En tu viewmodel debes tener toda la información que necesitas en la vista. En este caso para los radio buttons necesitamos dos valores. Local y Foránea.

Agrega al viewmodel una lista que usaremos para renderizar los radio buttons en la vista:

```
public class DireccionViewModel
{
    ...
    [Display(Name = "Tipo dirección")]
    public string TipoDir {get; set;}
    ...

    //las opciones de los radio buttons
    public IEnumerable<string> DirOptions { get; set; } = new List<string> {"foránea", "local"};
}
```

### La vista

En la vista lo que haremos es iterar la lista de opciones que tenemos en el viewmodel y llamar a `RadioButtonFor` para cada elemento. Tenerlo en una lista tiene la ventaja que si luego necesitas agregar otras opciones solo debes adicionar un elemento a la lista.

Para renderizar los radios y enlazarlo a tu propiedad `TipoDir` hacemos algo como esto:

```
@foreach (var opt in Model.DirOptions)
{
    <div class="radio">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.TipoDir, opt, new { @class = "form-control" }) @opt
        </label>
    </div>
}
```

Lo que estamos haciendo es llamando al helper siempre usando la misma propiedad del viewmodel a la que queremos enlazar la selección (`TipoDir`) con las posibles opciones del radio.

### El código javascript

La parte del código javascript no sé exactamente qué hace pero parece algun request ajax alserver enviando la info que tienes en el form. Deberás asegurarte de que aún funcione después de estos cambios. Por lo pronto lo único que sé que tendrás que cambiar es el nombre por el que buscas el radio button que cambia en el script:

```
<script>

    //fijate que ahora el radio button se llama TipoDir. Igual que la property del viewmodel.         
    $("[name=TipoDir]").on('change', function () {
        // tu codigo acá
    });

</script>
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Gracias Karel, tu ejemplo me sirvió. A partir de el encontré la solución.